# Postfix whitelisting several email domain

Tags: postfix, solaris

is there any way to whitelist certain email domain in postfix ?

eg. whitelisting (Hotmail.com. msn.com, Linkedin.com, gmail.com and yahoo.*) ?

this is for postfix install on my solaris box

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Postfix Whitelist before recipient restrictions](https://serverfault.com/questions/132750/postfix-whitelist-before-recipient-restrictions)

Answer (score 1):

Can I suggest before you ask the question you google "postfix whitelist" ?
Because the answer appears right away.

http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-whitelist-hosts-ip-addresses-in-postfix

Comment: That's not what he wanted to do. He wants to whitelist sender domains, not sending mail servers. So I guess a Google isn't as useful as you thought...also, it's not bad to ask questions that can be answered by Google. This is a Q & A site that can always use more info. It'd be nice if the first hit on Google brought you here, wouldn't it?

Comment: thanks Matt, I'm new bie in this area sorry about that, so shall I use "/etc/postfix/rbl_override" or "/etc/postfix/sender_access" I'm confused here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to refer you to an answer on another ServerFault question. Seems to be a perfect solution for what you want to do:

[Postfix Whitelist before recipient restrictions](https://serverfault.com/questions/132750/postfix-whitelist-before-recipient-restrictions/132781#132781)

Comment: Thanks Jason, the reason that I'd like to put those famous/well-known domain into whitelist is that because sometimes it gets block by SORBS list RBL